# Cannot install XBMC due to dependency issues

Tags: software-installation, xbmc

I am unable to install XBMC even after following all the steps...
This is the error message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xbmc : Depends: xbmc-bin (>= 2:12.2~git20130502.1706-frodo-0raring) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: xbmc-bin (< 2:12.2~git20130502.1706-frodo-0raring.1~) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable
        Depends: ttf-liberation but it is not installable
        Depends: python-bluez but it is not installable or
                 python-lightblue but it is not installable
        Depends: python-simplejson but it is not installable
        Depends: swig but it is not installable
        Depends: libnfs1 but it is not installable
        Depends: libcec2 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python-support (>= 0.90.0) but it is not installable
        Recommends: python-qt3 but it is not installable
        Recommends: libvdpau1 but it is not installable
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-mythtv-cmyth but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-vuplus but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-vdr-vnsi but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-njoy but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-nextpvr but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-mediaportal-tvserver but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-tvheadend-hts but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-dvbviewer but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: xbmc-pvr-argustv but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `sudo apt-get -f install` please?

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 130 not upgraded.

Comment: OK, how about `sudo dpkg --configure -a` ?

Comment: Did you try: **`sudo apt-get install xbmc xbmc-bin`**? What Ubuntu version? 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I am using 32 bit..I tried the above bin. same error message..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and am ubuntu noob, so it might be a beginner mistake.

I needed to enable sources from "Community-maintained free and open-source software (universe)"

Now installed