# ubuntu 12.04 python problem or?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, python

Hi i am trying to fix this for a long time but without success. When i open my zsh terminal i get this error: (terminal is working but error appear)

```
 Welcome to the world of tomorrow!
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied: 
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
```

I tried few things but... dont know how to solve it. Somehow during looking for a search i found i should post here an output of:

```
→ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up python-pip (1.0-1build1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-pip.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libc-dev-bin (2.15-0ubuntu10.5) ...
Setting up gnome-control-center-data (1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev (3.2.0-56.86) ...
Setting up python-virtualenv (1.7.1.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-virtualenv.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-virtualenv.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing python-virtualenv (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libglib2.0-0 (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-0:i386 (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gimp (2.6.12-1ubuntu1.2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gimp.postinst: 11: /var/lib/dpkg/info/gimp.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: error processing gimp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libpolkit-gobject-1-0 (0.104-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libgnome-control-center1 (1:3.4.2-0ubuntu0.13) ...
Setting up libnm-util2 (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up libc6-dev (2.15-0ubuntu10.5) ...
Setting up libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (1:1.1-0ubuntu15.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualenvwrapper:
 virtualenvwrapper depends on python-virtualenv; however:
  Package python-virtualenv is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing virtualenvwrapper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libpolkit-agent-1-0 (0.104-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libupower-glib1 (0.9.15-3git1ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up libaccountsservice0 (0.6.15-2ubuntu9.6.1) ...
Setting up libpolkit-backend-1-0 (0.104-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up libglib2.0-bin (2.32.4-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libnm-glib4 (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu4.3) ...
Setting up policykit-1 (0.104-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up gnome-settings-daemon (3.4.2-0ubuntu0.6.4) ...
Setting up accountsservice (0.6.15-2ubuntu9.6.1) ...
dpkg: error processing ubuntu-system-service (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pip
 python-virtualenv
 gimp
 virtualenvwrapper
 ubuntu-system-service
```

Also:

```
→ python --version
zsh: command not found: python
```

Part of my ~/.zshrc

```
# python virtual env wrapper
if [ -f ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh ]; then
    export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
    source ~/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
    plugins=("${plugins[@]}" virtualenvwrapper)
fi

# pythonbrew
[[ -s ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
```

Part os zsh -xv

```
#
# Invoke the initialization functions
#
virtualenvwrapper_initialize
+/home/trki/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh:1179> virtualenvwrapper_initialize
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:1> virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:1> typeset 'workon_home_dir=/home/trki/.virtualenvs'
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:5> [ /home/trki/.virtualenvs '=' '' ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:12> echo /home/trki/.virtualenvs
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:12> unset GREP_OPTIONS
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:12> grep '^[^/~]'
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:21> echo /home/trki/.virtualenvs
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:21> unset GREP_OPTIONS
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:21> egrep '([\$~]|//)'
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:30> echo /home/trki/.virtualenvs
+virtualenvwrapper_derive_workon_home:31> return 0
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:1> export 'WORKON_HOME=/home/trki/.virtualenvs'
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:3> virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home -q
+virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home:1> RC=0 
+virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home:2> [ ! -d /home/trki/.virtualenvs/ ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_verify_workon_home:11> return 0
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:6> [ /home/trki/.virtualenvs '=' '' ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:11> virtualenvwrapper_run_hook initialize
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:1> typeset hook_script
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:2> typeset result
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:4> hook_script=+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:4> virtualenvwrapper_tempfile initialize-hook
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:2> typeset 'suffix=initialize-hook'
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:3> typeset file
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:5> file=+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:5> virtualenvwrapper_mktemp -t virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXXXXXX
+virtualenvwrapper_mktemp:1> mktemp -t virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-XXXXXXXXXX
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:5> file=/tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7 
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:6> [ 0 -ne 0 ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:6> [ -z /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7 ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:6> [ ! -f /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7 ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:11> echo /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7
+virtualenvwrapper_tempfile:12> return 0
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:4> hook_script=/tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7 
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:11> cd /home/trki/.virtualenvs
+cd:1> [[ x/home/trki/.virtualenvs == x... ]]
+cd:3> [[ x/home/trki/.virtualenvs == x.... ]]
+cd:5> [[ x/home/trki/.virtualenvs == x..... ]]
+cd:7> [[ x/home/trki/.virtualenvs == x...... ]]
+cd:9> [ -d /home/trki/.autoenv ']'
+cd:13> cd /home/trki/.virtualenvs
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12> '' -m virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader --script /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7 initialize
virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:12: permission denied: 
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:15> result=126 
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:17> [ 126 -eq 0 ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:27> [ initialize '=' initialize ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:29> cat -
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenv has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON= and that PATH is
set properly.
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:38> rm -f /tmp/virtualenvwrapper-initialize-hook-OhY86PXmo7
+virtualenvwrapper_run_hook:39> return 126
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:13> virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion
+virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion:1> [ -n '' ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion:20> [ -n 4.3.17 ']'
+virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion:30> compctl -K _virtualenvs workon rmvirtualenv cpvirtualenv showvirtualenv
+virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion:31> compctl -K _cdvirtualenv_complete cdvirtualenv
+virtualenvwrapper_setup_tab_completion:32> compctl -K _cdsitepackages_complete cdsitepackages
+virtualenvwrapper_initialize:15> return 0
+/home/trki/.zshrc:17> plugins=( git python django symfony2 zsh-syntax-highlighting composer history-substring-search virtualenvwrapper ) 

# pythonbrew
[[ -s ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]] && source ~/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc
+/home/trki/.zshrc:21> [[ -s /home/trki/.pythonbrew/etc/bashrc ]]
```

Also when i try to open ubuntu software center absolutly nothing happens. No idea what to do now.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Could you add some more info about your environment? It seems that your `zsh` is configured to load some python environment - you should check `~/.zshrc` and `~/.zlogin` to see what it's failing.  Also running a different shell and running `zsh -xv` there should give you hints.

Comment: Thx. I updated info in my question but i am not much smarter from it :/ Any ideas what to do?

Comment: It seems you have packages badly installed, as if they had been held or force-installed or something similar. Have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f` to repair installation? And if you have held packages you can look [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/363244#363244). Moreover, what do you mean with "nothing happens" running software-center? try to run it from a terminal to see what it says...

Comment: i updated my question. Please have a look at it. (at the bottom). How can i run it from the terminal?

Comment: You can run `software-center` from command line in a terminal. However, this is clearly a problem related to the python virtualenv, and I do not know even what it is...

Comment: zsh: /usr/bin/software-center: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python: no such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I do not know anything about the python `virtualenv` you have installed, but it seems you have the packages in an inconsistent state. Probably a lot of problems arises from the fact that something is failing in your shell startup files and you have an half-baked environment up. So this is a **wild guess**, you should check with the support of the `virtualenv` thing you have.

**Disclaimer**: if you have installed things forcing the installation (you or some script) this can disrupt your system.

I would try to do the following:

1) try to see if it is automatically fixable:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

2) If this fails, try to see if you have "held" packages:

```
apt-mark showhold
```

3) if you have, un-hold them with:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package name>
```

And then repeat the step 1.

After that, probably the best thing you can do is removing all the packages that are creating problems with

```
sudo apt-get remove <package>
```

or even (you have played around with configuration files)

```
sudo apt-get purge <package>
```

and then reinstall them with `sudo apt-get install`. I would do this at least with the packages that give you error:

```
python-pip python-virtualenv gimp virtualenvwrapper ubuntu-system-service
```

and probably `zsh` too --- probably you'll have to remove/rename the `.zshrc`, `.zlogin`, `.zshenv` files too (if some installation script has modified them, reinstalling zsh will not change files in your home dir). Hope this helps...

Comment: everything i tried to remove ends up with http://pastebin.com/HMU8Aa4U

Comment: I really do not know what to suggest more. It seems you managed to have no python in your system, try to install or reinstall python-minimal (`sudo apt-get reinstall python-minimal`) but then I think you need to refer to he python-virtualenv developers. Something has really messed up your system.

Comment: Hmm but i think its not just with the python is it? Have a look at this please: http://pastebin.com/pg4jhqnY

Comment: Ubuntu will not work without python. And it seems that you do not have python installed. So, yes, I think it's not just python, but try to go step by step... Have you tried to reinstall python?

Comment: Did not know ubuntu will not work without python. And yea sure, several times and its kind of possible i mess something with paths or i had two different versions of python or something like that and i messed it all somehow :/ When i run python in zsh (terminal) there is no python, or python -v or --version returns nothing as well.