# Error while installing Shutter on Ubuntu 12.04!

Tags: 12.04, apt, shutter

I tried to install `shutter` with the following command, but I am receiving an error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install shutter
Shutter: 
Depends: gnome-web-photo but it is not installable
Depends: libgnome2-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgnome2-vfs-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgnome2-wnck-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgoo-canvas-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgtk2-imageview-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgtk2-trayicon-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libgtk2-unique-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libnet-dbus-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libproc-processtable-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libwww-mechanize-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libx11-protocol-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libxml-simple-perl but it is not installable
Depends: perlmagick but it is not installable
Depends: libpath-class-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libjson-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libjson-xs-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libnet-dropbox-api-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libfile-which-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libproc-simple-perl but it is not installable
Depends: libsort-naturally-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with Shutter some time ago, the reason is that you got broken dependencies.
Run this in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install -f
```

You can also use some Tweaks from time to time to clean your apt cache, configs, etc. For example Ubuntu Tweak, that what I used when this happend. After this I advice you to use Synaptic or Ubuntu Software Center to install Shutter.

Comment: try to run: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` it's good if you did it after removing broken packages. Sometimes a fresh OS restart also helps. Again what I used with terminal is Ubuntu Tweak:

    `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa`
    `sudo apt-get update`
    `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak`
    `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Start Janitor and clean everything.

Comment: If you really have held package, you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/363244#363244 --- unhold the held packages, remove them, and then reinstall.