# Cannot install Openssh-server or client

Tags: apt, ssh, software-installation, dependencies, openssh

When I go to install, I get this error:

`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

```
 Reading
 package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
 information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
 mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
 using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
 yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
 information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libxcb1 : Depends:
 libxau6 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxdmcp6 but it is not going to be installed  openssh-server : Depends: openssh-client (= 1:5.9p1-5ubuntu1)
                   Recommends: xauth but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: ssh-import-id but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this
 may be caused by held packages.
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4  When I try to install the dependencies listed, it says I have the newest versions.

Comment: You have held packages. Try to see if this answer can help you: http://askubuntu.com/a/363244/16395; in your case the problematic package seems to be libxcb1.

Comment: When check for held packages, it turns up nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 14.04. When I tried to install `openssh-server` (and any other software) I got the `E: Error, pkgProblemResolver` message while none of the packages were "hold".

The problem is caused by the versions of packages you try to install. The solution may involve removing and downgrading some of the packages you already have. You may use `aptitude` to get suggestions on how to solve the problem.

1. First, you must install `aptitude` if you do not have it

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```
2. Then, you can run the command indicating that you want to install the `openssh-server`

   ```
   $ sudo aptitude install openssh-server
   ```
3. The program will show you suggestions about how to solve the problem. Usually the first solution does not work. You can press `n` to request a new suggestion. Press `y` to accept a solution that installs the `openssh-server` and downgrades some other packages.