# MySQL 5.6 depends on client 5.5

Tags: server, mysql

I've installed Mysql-(server/client)-5.6 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS server
but for some programs I need mysql-client (automysqlbackup and postfix for example)

```
root@server:~# apt-get install automysqlbackup                  
 automysqlbackup : Depends: mysql-client
```

so:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server    
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client : Depends: mysql-client-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
```

and:

```
root@server:~# apt-get install mysql-client-5.6 mysql-server-5.6
 mysql-client-5.6 is already the newest version.
 mysql-server-5.6 is already the newest version.
```

Do I need to install mysql-(server/client)-5.5 alongside 5.6?

Comment: Look at this question: [Cannot install mysql-server-5.5/the following packages have unmet dependicies](http://askubuntu.com/questions/489815/cannot-install-mysql-server-5-5-the-following-packages-have-unmet-dependicies). *MySQL Client 5.5 and MySQL Server 5.5 are the current "best" versions of these packages in Ubuntu 14.04 as determined by the package maintainers.*, in case you don't need mysql-(server/client)-5.6 for some compelling reason.

Comment: This is a bug in `mysql-client` package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1287424 - mark it as affecting you.

Comment: well i kinda need it for another reason.
i would like to use the (new) inet6_pton function for IPv6 support. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1619332/1829460)

Answer (score 5):

If `automysqlbackup` can work with `mysql-client-5.6` (In other words, if it's binary compatible with `mysql-client-5.6`).

Is possible to use `equivs` to create dummy packages for `mysql-client`, `mysql-server`. Nothing to loose if it didn't work just uninstall them:

1. Install equivs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install equivs
   ```
2. Generate control file from template:

   ```
   equivs-control mysql-client
   ```
3. Open `mysql-client` file for edit. Change name and version if needed:

   ```
   ...
   Package: mysql-client
   Version: 5.6
   ...
   ```
4. Build then install it:

   ```
   equivs-build mysql-client
   sudo dpkg -i mysql-client*.deb
   ```

Follow same steps for `mysql-server`.

Comment: sorry for the delay..
i've tryed youre sollution but i ran into an error with equivs_build mysql-client.
`sh: 1: cannot open package: No such file
sh: 1: defaults: not found
`

Comment: @TD_Nijboer, :) me too, I was w/out Internet access. sorry I missed a step. see my updated answer.

Comment: Worked for me...

Comment: Worked for me also. Very nice. Any problems I need to watch out for in the future? Will Ubuntu try to upgrade this package or anything?

Comment: @flickerfly, No. As you see here http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mysql-client&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all , `mysql-client` package available only as version `5.5` in trusty and there will be no major upgrade, so it will never upgrade your local which is version `5.6`