# How to use equivs-build for creating deb from python app?

Tags: deb, pygtk

For my PyGtk application in Ubuntu I plan to use 'equivs-build' for the purpose of creating distribution deb file. The application is based on ./configure, make, make install . Any body suggest the step-by-step process to create the same...

Waiting for fast repsonse

Thanks
Anes

Answer (score 1):

- Similar to meta packages, follow instruction here: [How to create a meta-package that automatically installs other packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/33413/26246) or [MySQL 5.6 depends on client 5.5](https://askubuntu.com/q/497531/26246)
- You need more info to fill in equivs control file, documented in [`man equivs-build`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/equivs-build.1.html), example: `Files:` .