# "Backups" (deja-dup): after installing duplicity 0.8 from source, "Backups" can't find it

Tags: gnome, backup, restore, deja-dup, duplicity

When using "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup) - it doesn't find duplicity, although it's installed:

I have been trying to backup using "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup), and it turns out that the current duplicity (which deja-dup uses) still has the "Unicode bug" (it fails when dealing with Unicode strings).
(I have "Backups" (a.k.a. deja-dup) installed on my system: "deja-dup backup tool" v 37.0, and had duplicity v 0.7.17).

My system:

```
~$ lsb_release -a
Description:   Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS; Release:  18.04; Codename:   bionic
```

So, I then removed the existing installation of duplicity, and installed duplicity 0.8 from source: https://launchpad.net/duplicity. It installs duplicity at: /usr/local/bin. It's in PATH:

```
~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

After loading and installing all the requirements, duplicity 0.8 itself runs fine:

```
~$ duplicity -V
duplicity 0.8.05
```

But, when running "Backups" (deja-dup), it doesn't find it. A window pops up, saying:

> INSTALL PACKAGES
>
> In order to continue, the following package needs to
>   be installed: duplicity

I installed dconf-editor, found /org/gnome/deja-dup, but I don't see there any settings for the duplicity path.

nautilus and "apt list --installed" don't see it, either.

Note: cross posted [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/duplicity/+question/684905)

Comment: Duplicity by default on Ubuntu is installed in /usr/bin. You should try to install it there.

Comment: If no success, You may also try faking a Debian package like in https://askubuntu.com/a/497944/26246

Comment: @user.dz: "Backups" (=="deja-dup") must run duplicity, and it's not finding it because duplicity wasn't installed using the package management mechanism (dpkg | apt, etc.) but directly from tar. How do you make this happen using a fake package? (using equivs)?

Comment: @HelenCraigman, Yeah using `equivs`, create empty package with same name. Steps are  resumed in an answer from above link, You may also copy info from original package, check `CONTROL` file.

Comment: @user.dz: I think your comment is correct. (I looked around the net). Write it here as an answer, and I'll mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Deja-Dup does check for duplicity package instead of command, you may try faking a Debian package like in this case [MySQL 5.6 depends on client 5.5](https://askubuntu.com/q/497531/26246) , which is about a dependency issue.

[`equivs`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/equivs-build.1.html) may help to create dummy packages.

1. Install equivs:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install equivs
   ```
2. Generate control file from template:

   ```
   equivs-control duplicity
   ```
3. Open `duplicity` file for edit. Change name and version if needed:

   ```
   ...
   Package: duplicity
   Version: 0.8.05
   ...
   ```
4. Build then install it:

   ```
   equivs-build duplicity
   sudo dpkg -i duplicity*.deb
   ```

**Notes:**

- It can be uninstalled like any package. If you are using this method on large scale (company computers), write something in description (step 3) to indicate it's a dummy/fake package.
- For general case, some packages have [`Provides:..`](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html#virtual-packages-provides) field, check original package and copy that line from its `control` file, add it with step (3).

Answer (score 2):

To solve your original issue of Unicode errors, I would recommend trying the snap version of Deja Dup. It has the 0.8 version of duplicity bundled in.

Answer (score 1):

Programs can run with different PATH values. The most common that has bitten me is that `sudo` commands use a limited set of path values.

To Check the environment that a program is running with run `ps axeww | grep deja-dup`. The output will include the value of PATH used, towards the end of the output.

If the executable is not in the PATH used by deja-dup, you can add a symbolic link. For example to add a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/` run a command similar to the following.

`sudo ln -s  /usr/local/bin/duplicity /usr/bin`

Comment: Running "ps axeww | grep deja-dup", there is a "PATH" entry there, and the right path (/usr/local/bin) appears there. So that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Install snap version of duplicity, purge apt duplicity, and create link from snap to apt default location(/usr/bin/duplicity). And reboot.

See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1770929/comments/30