# MidiEditor error: Unmet Dependicies

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I was attempting to install MidiEditor. I got my file from the official downloads page (https://www.midieditor.org/index.php?category=download) but on both terminal and Ubuntu Software but they say the following error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfzhA.png
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
midieditor : Depends: qt5-default but it is not installable
Depends: gstreamer1.0-doc but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
I tried installing qt5-default, but it gave me a "E: Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate" error. Can anyone fix this?

**Edit:** Running MidiEditor gives nothing, running `midieditor` gives the following error:
 /usr/lib/midieditor/MidiEditor: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 22.04 "Jammy Jellyfish"

Comment: You can create a fake `qt5-default` package. https://askubuntu.com/a/1181415/124466 Let us know if there is any further issue.

Comment: I created the packages, but running `sudo apt .install /midi*.deb --fix-broken` gets me further except qt5-default is still halting the installation.

Comment: Did you install the fake qt5-default package first?

Comment: I did, but now entering `midieditor` in the prompt gives the following error: /usr/lib/midieditor/MidiEditor: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Multimedia.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `sudo apt install libqt5multimedia5`

Comment: @Archisman Panigraphi, It was saying for me to enter in `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and I did, but then I had to reinstall MidiEditor due to it randomly removing itself, and after plenty of typing commands (the command was `sudo apt install ~/qtbase5-dev*.deb ~/qt5-default*.deb /home/thes_real/Downloads/midieditor_3.3.0-1-amd64.deb` after building lots of packages) I got it to work, thank you!