# NodeJS install issues

Tags: nodejs

Whenever I need to use NodeJS I'm always tired of a bunch of problems.
At the moment I need to use closurecompiler nodejs module and try to install it and nodejs. It turns me following errors. How do I fix the problem ? I use Ubuntu 14.04
Before this I use:

```
sudo sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
```

and add other repository.  After this I executing:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
georgi@sepulcher:~$ sudo apt-get install nodejs 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nodejs
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4428 kB of archives.
After this operation, 17,7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 175393 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Setting up nodejs (0.10.30-1chl1~trusty1) ...
georgi@sepulcher:~$ sudo apt-get install npm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm : Depends: nodejs but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-abbrev (>= 1.0.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ansi but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-archy but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-block-stream but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream (>= 0.1.22) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-fstream-ignore but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-github-url-from-git but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-glob (>= 3.1.21) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-graceful-fs (>= 2.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-inherits but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-ini (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lockfile but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-lru-cache (>= 2.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-minimatch (>= 0.2.11) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-mkdirp (>= 0.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-gyp (>= 0.10.9) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-nopt (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-npmlog but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-once but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-osenv but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-retry but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-rimraf (>= 2.2.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-semver (>= 2.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-sha but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-slide but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-tar (>= 0.1.18) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-which but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://askubuntu.com/q/363200/299605

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nodejs` is in [Official Ubuntu Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nodejs). You can install it without adding new problem causing PPAs.

Remove the present `nodejs` and the Repository. Then install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to use node is to:

## [INSTALL BREW](http://brew.sh/linuxbrew/)

#### HERE IS HOW: PASTE IN TERMINAL

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Then at the end of your .bashrc file(In your home directory press Ctrl + H)

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Then restart terminal so the modification to .bashrc are reloaded

#### TO INSTALL NODE

```
brew install node
#to verify then type
node -v
npm -v
```

#### TO UPDATE NODE

```
brew update
brew upgrade node
```

#### TO UNINSTALL NODE

```
brew unistall node
```