# Errors when installing LAMP on my Ubuntu server (apache2-bin, mysql-client-5.5, mysql-serer-5.5, mysql-server-core-5.5, php5-common)

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lamp

I tried installing LAMP following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

the first command was: `$ sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`

Which gave me these errors:

[image]

I tried installing apache2 separetly but I still get the first error for apache2-bin.

I tried following these steps too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947426/apt-get-conflict-in-ubuntu
without any success.

**EDIT:**

Trying to install SSH server following this website: http://www.htpcbeginner.com/install-ssh-server-on-ubuntu-1204/

first command output for this: `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`:

[image]

**EDIT #2:**

Output for: `uname -a; lsb-release -a; libck-connector0; sudo apt-get install libck-connector0`

[image]

**EDIT #3**:

for susspicious outpust:

```
sudo apt-get install libck-connector0
```

[image]

and: `apt-get update; apt-cache policy libck-connector0`

[image]

**EDIT #4:**

`apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192; apt-get update`

[image]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @user4668401 the first one here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server 

Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS

Comment: The headachey part about diagnosing these is that you'll have to try and install each package one by one until you find out which packages in the entire reverse dependencies chain are a problem.

Comment: Install and start SSH on your server. After that, login from your host machine and run the installation of the task `lamp-server` again: `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` Now copy the output and paste to your question and remove the screenshot. Next run `uname -a; lsb-release -a; apt-cache policy apache2-bin lipapr1` and add talso this output to your question.

Comment: @A.B. Indeed, but the headache is that if you don't know *why* something's not installing you have to go through the entire chain ;)

Comment: @A.B. I edited my main post with a new error output for installing the SSH Server thing.

Comment: Please take in mind that this is my first install on a virtualbox so it maybe with the virtualbox and not the ubuntu itself. Just saying,,, keep open minded for that as a problem too...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your VirtualBox. [Edit] your question and add the output of `uname -a; lsb-release -a; libck-connector0; sudo apt-get install libck-connector0`

Comment: `apt-get update; apt-cache policy libck-connector0`

Comment: edited the mian post with outputs

Comment: `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192; apt-get update`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31996/discussion-between-a-b-and-hatul).

Comment: I edited the main post with the last output

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try something else:

- I see that at one point you had information, that you have held some packages, try to run `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold` to see those packages (they may be blocking other packages from being installed); if the list is empty, then proceed to the next point, if not, you can try to uninstall/purge some of those packages by hand
- if above does not help, try `apt-get -f install` - which should force finish any pending changes - if it uninstalls/installs any packages, run `apt-get update` and/or remove repo information and then try to install LAMP
- you can also try `apt-get autoremove`, but I've never seen such problems caused by unused packages, but who knows

Also found this to clean held packages:

- show held packages

> apt-mark showhold

- un-hold them by

> sudo apt-mark unhold [package name]

Source: [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that this instructions are for some older version of Ubuntu.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install apache2 mysql-client mysql-server php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

You will be asked for all necessary passwords during installation process.
Apache and MySQL will be started automatically and addedd to start at boot.
I'd also recommend installing `phpmyadmin` for database operations.

Comment: I get the exact same errors.

Comment: did you do apt-get update before?

Answer (score -1):

Its possible that the repositories from where you are trying to install from have changed since your iso image was created.
Try running these commands:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This will remove the package lists. No repositories will be deleted, they are configured in the config file in `/etc/apt/sources.list`. All that can happen is that tools like `apt-cache` cannot get package information unless you updated the package lists. 
Also `apt-get install` will fail with `E: Unable to locate package <package>`, because no information is available about the package.

Then

```
apt-get clean
```

`apt-get clean` clears out the local repository of retrieved package files. It removes everything but the lock file from `/var/cache/apt/archives/` and `/var/cache/apt/archives/partial/`.

finally

```
apt-get update
```

to rewrite those lists.