# Can't install libsfml-dev on 16.10; unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I'm new to Linux, but I'm really interested in learning it and using it as my main development platform. I'm running into trouble, though, installing a library I use in my projects.

Whenever I try to install SFML with `sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev` I end up with an error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libsfml-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dev but it is not going to be installed or
                        libgl-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And if I try to `sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev` I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dev : Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx (= 12.0.3-1ubuntu2) but 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`
```

Like I said, I'm new to Linux and have more or less no idea what I'm doing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: try this: `sudo apt update`, then `sudo apt full-upgrade`, after that try again

Comment: Please refer to my (kolim) solution at http://askubuntu.com/questions/841114/ubuntu-unable-to-install-any-packages-held-broken-packages/872639#872639

Comment: @George `sudo apt full-upgrade` did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: Let me drop an answer for your acceptance, glad it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to always do `update` and `upgrades` before and after any installation, so run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```