# Ubuntu:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: python

I am trying to install ImageMagick Library.
with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
```

But It give error like:

```
libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand5 (= 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmagickcore5-extra (= 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.4) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libmagickcore-dev (= 8:6.7.7.10-6ubuntu3.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is the solution of this type of problem?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and try again

Comment: Its not working,still same error is occured.

Comment: Manually install the **depends** packages that are not going to be installed.

Comment: 'Held broken packages' often means a *version conflict*, usually caused by unsupported software from PPAs or other non-Ubuntu sources. Disable the source that is causing the problem, and uninstall all software from that source. Is this your very first try to install imagemagick packages? If not, what did you try before?

Comment: its work when I install the depends manually

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement.  I'll place this in the answer.

Comment: Please refer to my solution at http://askubuntu.com/questions/841114/ubuntu-unable-to-install-any-packages-held-broken-packages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First ensure your system's libraries are update by running:

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
```

Then manually install the **Depends** that are displayed in the error message.

Then install the package as normal.

Comment: Ran into this issue as well. I had selected to download from "fastest mirror" in the "Software & Updates" section. I WAS able to fix it by "apt-get update" and "apt-get upgrade" but ONLY AFTER switching back to "Server for United States"

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem.

system: Linux mint 18.1 "Serena"

When I did like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

Outcomes:

> sudo: unable to resolve host mint
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>   vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2+git20170601+r59025+56~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
>         Depends: libavcodec-ffmpeg56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed or
>                  libavcodec-ffmpeg-extra56 (>= 7:2.4) but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I tried many methods that i can search on the net, such like:

```
$ sudo apt-get update 
$ sudo apt-get upgrade

$ sudo apt-get update --fix-missing

$ sudo apt-get autoclean $$ apt-get clear cache
```

and so on.

But those can help me to solve the problem.

I also see `Synaptic Package Manager --> Custom Filters --> Broken`, there were no broken package.

Finally, I changed the **software source**, then I tried

```
 $ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

The problem was solved.