# Error: build-essential : Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, g++, redis

I'm trying to install build-essential using `sudo apt-get install build-essential` command.
I get this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
build-essential : Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I am installing build-essential so that I can  install redis after. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888098/ubuntuunable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good use for the **APT Master Recovery Commands**:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

These commands will update your local package cache, attempt to fix any broken packages with dependency issues, and then run a full system upgrade.

Once all of these things are done, go ahead and try installing `build-essential` again.