# Unable to install Python pip in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, pip

I ran `sudo apt-get install python-pip` from terminal. But I got the following error :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pip
```

And when I ran the commmand `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential.` from terminal, I got the following error :-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-setuptools
E: Unable to locate package python-dev
E: Unable to locate package build-essential.
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'build-essential.'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'build-essential.'
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that all Ubuntu repositories(`main`, `universe`, `restricted`, `multiverse`) are not enabled. That's why, you are getting `Unable to locate <package>` errors. To do it, run the following commands(one-by-one) from Terminal :-

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update
```

Also in the second command, i.e. `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential.`, you didn't name the package `build-essential`correctly. So you got this error :-

```
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'build-essential.'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'build-essential.'
```

You can use a different method to install **pip** in Ubuntu 17.10. To do it, run the following commands(one-by-one) from Terminal :-

```
sudo apt install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o /tmp/get-pip.py
sudo python3 /tmp/get-pip.py
pip install --user pipenv
echo "PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
```

**References**

- [“Unable to locate package” while trying to install packages with APT](https://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-with-apt)
- [How to install pip and pipenv properly on Ubuntu 17.10](https://vandragt.com/blog/2017/10/how-to-install-pip-and-pipenv-properly-on-ubuntu-17-10/)

Answer (score 4):

Have you downloaded the apt package registry? Make sure you start with a `$ sudo apt update`, confirm you can get package updates with `$ sudo apt update -y`

Also, make sure your system isn't busted. Perhaps post your error messages?
[Can't install python-pip](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892084/cant-install-python-pip?rq=1)

Comment: This worked in my case, I was having the same error. After doing {sudo apt update}. It prompted me to {sudo apt upgrade}. This resolved the issue. Thanks!