# Unable to install Mongo due to held broken packages

Tags: apt, upgrade, ppa, mongodb

If I try to install mongo on Ubuntu 14.04 with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[This similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) recommends running `apt-mark showhold` to find the held packages and unhold them, but it shows nothing being held.

What's causing this error and how do I fix it?

I'm installing Mongo from Mongo's PPA. And I had previously had PPAs enabled for both the 3.0 and 3.4 versions. I removed the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list` for the 3.0 version, to avoid conflicts, but I think there still might be some lingering issues.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and the problem was that libcurl3 wasn't installed.
this should work.

```
sudo apt install libcurl3
```

Comment: for newer versions of ubuntu it will be `sudo apt install libcurl4`

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't immediately obvious, but when I went [back over the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/), I realized I installed the PPA for the wrong Ubuntu version. Removing that and installing the correct one fixed the error.

Comment: What did you remove and how?