# Python3 pip3 install broken on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, python-2.7, pip

I installed python3 and pip3 successfully on my Ubuntu16.04, but pip3 install is broken. How can I fix this problem? The error information of `pip3 install` is as follows:

```
# pip3 install xlwt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
  from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

Output of `sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip`

```
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
  from pip import main
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
  from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

Output of `which pip3` and `pip3 --version`:

```
# which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3

# pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarning
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.requests'
```

P.S. Python2 pip runs successfully. Output of "which pip" and "pip --version":

```
# which pip
/usr/bin/pip

# pip --version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

And python and python3 installation information:

```
# which python
/usr/bin/python
# which python3
/usr/bin/python3

# python -V
Python 2.7.14
# python3 -V
Python 3.6.3
```

Comment: You said 16.04 in your post but used the 14.04 tag. Which version is correct?

Comment: 16.04 is correct. I couldn't find the 16.04 tag just now. Sorry.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is something wrong with your pip3 so remove it and reinstall it. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip  
sudo rm -rf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip'  
sudo apt install python3-pip   
cd
cd .local/lib/python3/site-packages
sudo rm -rf pip*  
cd
cd .local/lib/python3.5/site-packages
sudo rm -rf pip*  
python3 -m pip install xlwt
```

Comment: I tried but still the same error: https://imgur.com/a/nAdqU .

Comment: I am having the same issue too. When I do `sudo apt install python3-pip`, I get the following error: `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python-pip-whl (= 8.1.1-2) but 8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
               Recommends: build-essential but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-wheel but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: @Kristada673 Try reading the answers to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages. DragonLord's answer worked for me.

Comment: @karel What's the purpose of the `--user` parameter on your last command line?  Without explanation, it looks like something specific to your environment.

Answer (score 6):

Installing python3-pip package create a python script in file /usr/bin/pip3. In order to run, main() function need to be imported from module pip (`from pip import main`).
This method path is only available for packaged pip version (9.0.1 in my case).

After running `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, pip version become 18.1, and main() has been moved in `pip._internal`.

Use the command `python3 -m pip --version` to see if your case correspond to the same situation (pip3 is also available with this method when `/usr/bin/pip3` is broken).

If so, in file /usr/bin/pip3, replace line 9:
`from pip import main`
with:
`from pip._internal import main`

The issue will be fixed.
(Tested on Ubuntu 18.04 distribution)

Comment: After I changed the import, a different error shows up `File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Answer (score 3):

This is what I've found helpful:

1. `sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`
2. Never run `pip3` within `sudo`.

Comment: While that maybe fixes things, can you please expand your answer ?  Why to remove this directory (maybe add a caveat about the `python3.5` path), why never to run it with sudo, and so on..

Comment: I am not quite an expert on this - I just wanted to share what had worked for me.

Comment: [I really can't recommend this approach.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1009371/757139)

Comment: After hours of searching SO and SE, this is the only thing that fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

First delete the corrupted pip3:

```
rm /user/bin/pip3 /user/local/bin/pip3
```

Reinstall the new one:

```
sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, installing openssl fixed it for me

Comment: But openssl already install on my Ubuntu: https://imgur.com/a/60kIM . Maybe it's caused by another reason.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vincent H. mentioned, i encountered the same issue.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ashish/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in 
>       from pip._internal import main ImportError: No module named 'pip._internal'

The fix to the issue was to replace `pip._internal` to `pip` in `.local/bin/pip3` by doing `sudo gedit .local/bin/pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an problem but u can solution.

```
rm /user/bin/pip3 /user/local/bin/pip
sudo apt-get remove python-pip
```

than reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Answer (score 0):

u may do this:

```
sudo apt purge python3-pip  
sudo rm -rf '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip'  
sudo apt install python3-pip
sudo cp /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/
```

This worked for me when my pip3 was broken