# curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.14) but 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed

Tags: apt, software-installation

I can't install curl. 
I get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 curl : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.14) but 7.55.1-1ubuntu2.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I installed libcurl3, but I can't install curl. What should I do?

Comment: You installed something that depends upon a 14.04 version (7.35.0) of libcurl3 instead of 17.10 (7.55.1). You cannot mix packages from different releases of Ubuntu - they are *incompatible*. Uninstall the 14.04-era package(s).

Comment: How can I do? Comment remove doesn't work.

Comment: Well, what did you last install before this problem began?

Comment: I want to install composer. I only installed update system.

Comment: So uninstall libcurl3, and READ CAREFULLY what else the system wants to uninstall. How did you install libcurl3? It's rather difficult to mix versions unless you really try hard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to user535733

I finally figured it out! It was problem with libcurl3 cause it was older version libcurl that was of 16.04LTS. I uninstalled libcurl 3 by
    sudo apt-get remove libcurl3
and tried
    sudo apt-get install curl
and Bam It worked!