# Can't install vim on Ubuntu 18.04 because of broken python package

Tags: package-management, vim

I'm having problems installing vim on my upgraded Ubuntu. When I try to install vim:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

I get this error saying I have broken packages.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
vim : Depends: libpython3.6 (>= 3.6.4~rc1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried fixing this with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
```

My python version is 3.6.5. So I am rather confused that something is missing for vim. Because before my upgrade to 18.04 I had vim installed and it worked fine.

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

Doesn't show any held packages either.

But I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

I fixed the issue by downgrading my python packages to the version vim was requesting. Thanks for the help. I solved the issue with

```
sudo aptitude install -f vim
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: this might help. https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: instead of the edit to your question, could you [edit] your question, remove it there and post an answer???  If you leave a comment @Fabby, I'll come back and upvote too!

Comment: I've got the same problem after upgrading to 18.04. For me the solution was to install a fork of vim : `apt install neovim`