# can't download wine

Tags: wine, 19.10

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 and was downloading wine 5.0 and after adding the repository i ran this.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

and it gives me this.

```
    Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fixnix/netspeed/ubuntu eoan InRelease           
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security InRelease [97.5 kB]      
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/persepolis/ppa/ubuntu eoan InRelease            
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                  
Hit:7 http://eg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan InRelease                       
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/plushuang-tw/uget-stable/ubuntu eoan InRelease  
Fetched 97.5 kB in 1s (67.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 5.0.0~eoan)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: I see no fewer than *five* non-Ubuntu sources listed in your output, so a "*you have requested an impossible situation*" warning is not surprising. Wean yourself away from so many PPAs, and your system will start working again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: @David No it doesn't thank you.

Comment: @user535733 it actually solved the problem after removing some PPAs thank you.

Comment: @N0rbert No it doesn't thank you.

Comment: @karel No it doesn't thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed some unimportant PPAs and it worked again.