# Unable to install packages (unmet dependencies / broken packages)

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies

I am trying to use "sudo apt-get install build-essential" but it gives an error:

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
> requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
> distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
> or been moved out of Incoming.
> The following information may help to resolve the situation:
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> build-essential : Depends: libc6-dev but it is not going to be installed or
> libc-dev
> Depends: gcc (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: g++ (>= 4:7.2) but it is not going to be installed
> Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.17.11) but it is not going to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I tried to install the dependent packages (libc6-dev) etc but it ends up with

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
> E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

So I try to install libc6

> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> libc6 is already the newest version (2.27-3ubuntu1.2).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

When I use aptitude instead

> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> build-essential dpkg-dev{ab} fakeroot{a} g++{a} g++-7{ab} gcc{a}
> gcc-7{ab} libalgorithm-diff-perl{a} libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl{a}
> libalgorithm-merge-perl{a} libasan4{ab} libatomic1{ab} libc-dev-bin{a}
> libc6-dev{ab} libcilkrts5{ab} libfakeroot{a} libgcc-7-dev{ab} libitm1{ab}
> liblsan0{ab} libmpx2{ab} libquadmath0{ab} libstdc++-7-dev{ab}
> libtsan0{ab} libubsan0{ab} linux-libc-dev{a} manpages-dev{a}
> 0 packages upgraded, 26 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 26.6 MB of archives. After unpacking 116 MB will be used.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
> libgcc-7-dev : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libmpx2 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.27-3ubuntu1) but 2.27-3ubuntu1.2 is installed
> libitm1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libcilkrts5 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libasan4 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libstdc++-7-dev : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libtsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libubsan0 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> g++-7 : Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> gcc-7 : Depends: cpp-7 (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> Depends: gcc-7-base (= 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) but 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-8-base (= 8-20180414-1ubuntu2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
> dpkg-dev : Depends: libdpkg-perl (= 1.19.0.5ubuntu2) but 1.19.0.5ubuntu2.3 is installed
> The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
> Keep the following packages at their current version:

1. ```
    build-essential [Not Installed]
   ```
2. ```
    dpkg-dev [Not Installed]
   ```
3. ```
    g++ [Not Installed]
   ```
4. ```
    g++-7 [Not Installed]
   ```
5. ```
    gcc [Not Installed]
   ```
6. ```
    gcc-7 [Not Installed]
   ```
7. ```
    libasan4 [Not Installed]
   ```
8. ```
    libatomic1 [Not Installed]
   ```
9. ```
    libc6-dev [Not Installed]
   ```
10. ```
    libcilkrts5 [Not Installed]
    ```
11. ```
    libgcc-7-dev [Not Installed]
    ```
12. ```
    libitm1 [Not Installed]
    ```
13. ```
    liblsan0 [Not Installed]
    ```
14. ```
    libmpx2 [Not Installed]
    ```
15. ```
    libquadmath0 [Not Installed]
    ```
16. ```
    libstdc++-7-dev [Not Installed]
    ```
17. ```
    libtsan0 [Not Installed]
    ```
18. ```
    libubsan0 [Not Installed]
    ```

Accepting the solution gives:

> No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
> 0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look backward: What was the last deb-based software, from any source, that you tried to install? Regardless of success or failure, that is the most likely cause. If you do not remember, refresh your memory using /var/log/apt/history.log and /var/log/apt/term.log

Comment: Could you open Software Sources and see if under the Updates tab that both the updates and security sources are enabled. If not, enable them, reload your sources (or sudo apt update) & see if better..

Comment: The best option for solving this problem is to study [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1081938/) to [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages). It's good for solving difficult broken packages problems. Start with the *Edit* -> *Fix Broken Packages* because this is a big problem and using a GUI app to solve it would help to solve it faster.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if we can find the the broken packages.

In a terminal, type:

```
$ sudo apt-mark showhold
```

If it returns something, then we can do this:

```
$ sudo apt-mark unhold {package_name}
```

From there, you should be able to retry the installation:

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
$ sudo apt clean
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install build-essential
```

If this doesn't work, [`aptitude` might resolve the issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages/451078#451078).

Comment: showhold returns nothing
retrying installation returns same error
you can see from my original post that aptitude is unable to resolve my error either. thanks for the attempt