# Cant install php8-dev on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, php, dmcrypt

I have Ubuntu 20.04 system installed, and I want to install mcrypt php extension. after I installed xampp server, I tried to install mcrypt so I need to install php-dev package first but I am getting this error.

```
sajad@ubuntu-latitude-e7450:~$  **sudo apt install php8.0-dev**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php8.0-dev : Depends: libpcre2-dev (>= 10.30) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libtool (>= 2.4.6-0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.**
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy php-dev php8.0-dev libpcre2-dev libtool` to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)