# when upgrading ubuntu , it says broken packages

Tags: upgrade, dependencies

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed : Depends: grub-efi-amd64-bin (= 2.06-2ubuntu7)
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: `2.06-2ubuntu7` = `jammy / main`. This suggests that might not have `jammy-updates` enabled. You should have both `jammy-updates` and `jammy-security` enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)